# How do I replace the first character in a String with a char inside a regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String, which represents an ID of a product. This String should begin with one of the chars of this regex: **[a-zA-Z_:]** How can I replace the first character in the ID with one of the chars in the regex in case the ID starts not with the char of the regex?
Example: "?rtg" starts with a question mark and not with an upper case letter and not with a lower case letter and not with an underscore and not with a colon, but I need it to start with one of those chars. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Provide examples of input and replaced strings.

Comment: In string `"?rtg"` what should it be replaced with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the string ID is to be checked, you can do:

```
ID = ID.replaceFirst("^[^a-zA-Z_:]", "a");
```

This replaces the first character of ID, if it is not one of the valid chars, with 'a'.

This will print "artg" for the given "?rtg" 
and "bcde" for the given "bcde".

Comment: The question was bad written. I figured out now, what it should be replaced with. I am sorry for the dummy question!

Comment: No reason to be sorry. There are no dummy questions

Comment: That's probably because it was not very well written, as you didn't provide examples of desirable input/output and what you have tried. These are minimum requirements for a good question. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to edit this question afterwards, for practice.